# Add just files in current directory into .7z file without recursing directories

Tags: linux, bash, 7zip

I want to add/update just the files of the current directory into archive.7z without recursing into lower directories. This works, but it's slow due to initialization for each file:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f | while read f;do 7za a ~/archive.7z "$f" ; done
```

This also works, and is much faster, but unsure how bulletproof it is for problematic file names with spaces and other problematic chars:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -r0 7za a ~/archive.7z --
```

Shouldn't there be a more elegant way? Like with `-T -` in the `tar` command. I'm currently using 7za version 9.20 on Ubuntu16. Variants such as these below failed, they started recursing into lower directories which I don't want:

```
7za a -r- ~/archive.7z .
7za a -r- ~/archive.7z ./
7za a -r- ~/archive.7z *
7za a -r- ~/archive.7z -- *.*
7za a -r- ~/archive.7z -- "*"
7za a -r0 ~/archive.7z -- *.*
```

Answer (score 1):

```sh
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec 7z a archive.7z {} +
```

This way you call one `7z` process (contrary to the syntax `-exec {} \;`) and this is expected to be fast. In fact it will use up to the maximum allowed arguments before raising a second process.

---

Also, regarding your query about filenames. The while loop is not acceptable. `find -print0 | xargs -0` is good and fast. In general, you have to zero separate the output of `find` and read it as zero separated input on the next processing, to preserve filenames.

Comment: The xargs solution above should run 7z the same number of times as the solution only using find. The pure-find solution does look cleaner, but the piped version might actually be faster since find can continue iterating the filesystem while xargs has spawned the first process.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @B.Morris, I updated the answer. xargs will be fast also indeed. The only caveat is that could complain for argument list too long in case of too many files, which (might be more necessary for this job)a and the find part usually is overall tiny comparing to the zipping part.

Comment: `xargs` will spawn multiple processes if needed, too.

Comment: @B.Morris Do you mean that, for example [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83801/find-xargs-argument-line-too-long) if we get "arguments list too long" for xargs, we also get it for find alone? And both `exec +` and `xargs -0` are avoiding that in any case?

Comment: Based on the accepted answer to that post, I think that might have been xargs usage error. The general behavior of xargs is to spawn as many processes as needed to handle all input lines. You can further limit the number of arguments per process but by default it should use the maximum supported.

Comment: ok, i will modify the answer to keep only confirmed statements, and try to get some more info later on this. Cheers.